# Using Products.ResourceRegistries 2.1.2 on plone 4.1.4

Tags: plone

I would like to use plone.app.jquery 1.7.2 on my plone 4.1.4, but it doesn't work because plone 4.1.4 use an old version of Products.ResouceRegistries that doesn't enable the "bundle" option.

So I figure myself that I have to update Products.ResouceRegistries to 2.1.2.
I have modified the versions.cfg and run buildout, but with no effect (no download of the new version).

How could I update the version ?

Comment: It should work like you described, I tested that on a P415. Is it possible one of the 3rd-party-products is pinning ResourceRegistries, too?

Comment: pinning work, so show us how you are trying to pin it and we will find your typo.

Comment: Ok, found that I have this line in my buildout : http://good-py.appspot.com/release/dexterity/1.2.1?plone=4.1.4 this version pin Products.ResouceRegistries to 2.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there is a kgv in the buildout that pinned Products.ResouceRegistries to 2.0.6 :
http://good-py.appspot.com/release/dexterity/1.2.1?plone=4.1.4

Removing the ?plone=4.1.4 and pin Products.ResouceRegistries to 2.1.2 make it works.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just upgrade to Plone 4.2?

Comment: because it's the easyest way ;)